# Prove the rank of the direct sum of two linear transformations (on finite-dimensional vector spaces) is the sum of their ranks.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

I would like to show the rank of the direct sum of two linear transformations (on finite-dimensional vector spaces) is the sum of their ranks.

**Definition**: Let $M$ and $N$ be any two vector spaces, and let $A$ and $B$ be any two linear transformations (on $M$ and $N$ respectively). let $V$ be the direct sum of $M$ and $N$, then we define on $V$ a linear transformation $C$ called the direct sum of $A$ and $B$, by writing $Cz=C(x,y)=(Ax,By)$.

**Definition**: The rank of a linear transformation is the dimension of the range.

$Source$: Halmos Finite Demensional Vector Space section 48-51 exercise#4.

I am pretty much lose, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could provide the definition of a direct sum (as given in Halmos).

Comment: yeah, thank you, I have added the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $C = A \oplus B: M \oplus N \to M' \oplus N'$. 
let $x_1,\dots,x_m \in M$ be such that $A(x_1),\dots,A(x_m)$ is a basis of the image of $A$.  Let $y_1,\dots,y_n \in N$ be such that $B(y_1),\dots,B(y_n)$ is a basis of the image of $B$.

Show that the set
$$
\{(A(x_1),0),(A(x_2),0),\dots,(A(x_m),0),(0,B(x_1)),\dots,(0,B(x_n))\}
$$
is a basis of the image of $C$ (which is simply the direct sum of the images of $A$ and $B$).

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. so I think I need to show that the set
$$
\{(A(x_1),0),(A(x_2),0),\dots,(A(x_m),0),(0,B(x_1)),\dots,(0,B(x_n))\}
$$ is an linearly independent set and spans the image of $C$. Spanness is obviously. so I only need to show the set is linearly independent. is that right?

Comment: Really what you need to show is that the image of the direct sum of transformations is the direct sum of the images of the transformations.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to show linear independence if you were to prove things as I've outlined (which is basically from definitions).  Then again, you might be able to exploit some statement in the textbook that, in general, $U \oplus V$ has dimension $\dim(U) + \dim(V)$.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think the way to show the linear independence, use the general method as $$a_1(A(x_1,0))+...+a_(m+n)(0,B(x_n)=0$$, and then take the each coordinate we can show the set is linearly independence by using the linearly independence of the set of each basis of the image of $A$ and $B$. will that be OK?

Comment: That should be perfect

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot :D